# What awesome foo.stackexchange am I not a member of but should be?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, subjective

Background: I'm only active on Stackoverflow, but other interesting Stack Exchange sites have been drifting into my view.

Are there any that have matched or surpassed the original in terms of awesomeness?

Comment: I'd say that depends on what kinds of things you're interested in?

Comment: Let's say I'm your average SO member: professional programmer and interested in technology.

Comment: From your profile, it looks like you're pretty much already a member of everything...

Comment: I've logged in before, but I'm not active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place to find new sites to join.

[image]

In your case you'll want to hit the [Technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology) tab on the bottom left, then click on either [`beta`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=beta) or [`launched`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=launched) on the top right to find sites that are currently active.